# apply release file to CDROM .iso

Tags: debian

I downloaded the Debian 11 Bullseye .iso and everything needed to check it:

```
debian-11.3.0-amd64-DVD-1.iso  SHA256SUMS  SHA256SUMS.sign  SHA512SUMS  SHA512SUMS.sign
```

Ran the checks, everything okay.

The first line in `/etc/apt/sources.list` is

```
deb cdrom:[Debian GNU/Linux 11.3.0 _Bullseye_ - Official amd64 DVD Binary-1 20220326-11:23]/ bullseye contrib main
```

I keep that commented out otherwise every time an update is run it complains about a release file.

How can you tell it to trust just that one file - which I manually checked but without switching off all other associated security features?

Typically the file will be mounted. It finds the CDROM but it does not trust it.

Answer (score 1):

You have made use of the contents of the ISO file to install Debian, and the install has configured on-line package repositories that make the unchanging ISO image obsolete.

After my install is finished, I remove the cdrom line from my sources.list files and use the on-line repositories.

Comment: The image was of course used to make a bootable CD drive. Then I placed and let the ISO file sit in the downloads directory. I think you're wrong though - it was actually a DVD image 3.8GB big. I believe it only uses a fraction of that for the standard install, and there is a lot on there which can be used as a static source, as well as online source of course.

Answer (score 0):

I've mainly fixed it, the release file message has gone away.

As per [instructions](https://wiki.debian.org/DebianInstaller/Modify/CD#Creating_New_Packages_and_Release_Files_and_Fixing_md5sum.txt) from the Debian official site I changed

```
deb cdrom:[Debian GNU/Linux 11.3.0 _Bullseye_ - Official amd64 DVD Binary-1 20220326-11:23]/ bullseye contrib main
```

to

```
deb [trusted=yes] cdrom:[Debian GNU/Linux 11.3.0 _Bullseye_ - Official amd64 DVD Binary-1 20220326-11:23]/ bullseye contrib main
```

in `/etc/apt/sources.list`

It's still telling me to to something with `apt-cdrom` to recognise the mounted cdrom but it seems to be going through the cdrom now and not complaining about a release file.